# ¿La pila de llamadas es también la encargada de almacenar los datos en memoria en JavaScript o existe otra pila que haga esa función?

Tags: javascript, manejo-de-memoria, memoria

Quisiera saber si la pila de llamadas es la que almacena los datos en memoria junto con el montón en JavaScript o existe otra pila aparte de la pila de llamadas que realiza esta función. Tengo claro que la función de la pila de llamadas es administrar los contextos de ejecución en JavaScript pero no sé si más allá de eso cumpla con otra función.

Comment: su nombre lo dice: *pila de llamadas*

Comment: El encargado de la memoria es el recolector de basura. La pila solo guarda la función que se llama, quién lo llamó, los parámetros provistos y el contexto. El contexto y los parámetros pueden hacer referencia a valores pasados por valor, que en javascript estos serían los primitivos. De lo contrario harían referencia a memoria administrada por el recolector de basura. No obstante, la pila en sí no administra la memoria.